# Bootstrap - combine collapse with segmented buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap form and would like to combine segmented buttons with collapse js.  I'm wanting to have a search form with two segmented buttons: "+" and "Search".  When the "+" button is clicked, a collapsible well appears with filter options.  The well should extend the length of the search box.  I know this wrong, but I'm trying to something like this:

```html
<div class="input-group">

  <input type="text" class="form-control">

  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFilter">
      +
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      Search
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseFilter">
      <div class="well">
        Refine Search
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a proper way to nest these so that they can function together?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: its better to use a col-lg-12 or similar classes to both of them, so that both will have equal length..

Comment: Do you mean both divs (input-group & input-group-btn)?  That does seem to improve things.  The well is working, but the buttons are not lined up correctly.  Sorry, I am a bit css illiterate.

Comment: lined up means? you want to line them in single row? or as seperate rows?

Comment: I want them to be lined up like the example here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-multiple Right now they are on seperate rows with some spacing between the buttons (since I removed the input-group-btn class I think).

Comment: if you want all of them in a single row, you should provide proper rows and column classes. you may check the dropdown button on the link you gave

Comment: One final question...if I paste the collapsible well where it says <!-- Button and dropdown menu -->, the well only expands under the buttons in the button group.  I also want it to expand under the text box.

Comment: i have posted an answer for your question, hopes that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you needed

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group row">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFilter">
      +
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      Search
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseFilter">
    <div class="well">
      Refine Search
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awsome. That's exactly what I was after! Many thanks @Adarsh Mohan.